# Make requests as my .net core web application

Tags: c#, azure, razor-pages

I have created a web application through visual studio and used the options to authenticate my user with Azure automatically.

I want to make requests to Azure as the application, how do i do this?

So far I've tried using restSharp and making requests but it is asking for headers.

(I've not posted any code as I'm not sure where to find the information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a service principal.

Go to App Registrations, register an app, generate a secret, and then you can use that secret + app id, to get a token as the app.
The app registration will appear as an identity, so you can assign access to it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app

If you are hosting your web app as an App Service, you can use Managed identity, it will basically create an identity together with your app service, and then at runtime, it will have the secrets inside of environment variables. So you don't need to do app registration or secrets management.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview

A good example of how the entire flow looks is the key vault guide. The app calls Azure services(or specifically key vault) as itself, not as an user that is using the app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app